# ggplot: Adding alpha value to a whole layer

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to plot some boxplots as semi-transparent. When I set the `alpha` value, only the fill transparency is adjusted, and not the borders/strokes/colors.

Any idea how to make the whole geom layer transparent?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(cyl), color = factor(cyl)), alpha = 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work out of the box, since for polygons `ggplot2` only applies `alpha` to `fill`, not `colour`. In order to fix that, we'll apply the following ad-hoc patch by taking low-level internals and adding `alpha` mapping where needed.

Check out [the following gist](https://gist.github.com/tonytonov/a6145969fd6ec8cb1bc262a93f0a9759). Won't post it here, as it is too lengthy.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(cyl), color = factor(cyl)), alpha = 0.4, size = 1.4)
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @tonytonov !

Comment: After testing it out, it can't find the PolygonGrob for other kinds of plot (Like violin plots)
Error in polygonGrob(munched$x, munched$y, default.units = "native", id = munched$group,  : 
  could not find function "polygonGrob"